# Insertion Bulk data not work - elastic search

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana-4, sense

so basically im trying new things. this time with elastic search.
i already install elastic and kibana, and sense plugin of course.
i try all basic command like create index, mapping, adding document etc.
everything goes well until i try bulk insertion.

```
POST /ecommerce/product/_bulk
{"index":{"_id":"1002"}}
{"name":"SWA magazine", "price":"90.000", "description":"swa magazine description",
"status":"active", "quantity":3, "categories":[{"name":"magazine"}], 
"tags":["business", "magazine", "sales", "news"]}
{"index":{"_id":"1003"}}
{"name":"SWA magazine", "price":"90.000", "description":"swa magazine description",
"status":"active", "quantity":3, "categories":[{"name":"magazine"}], 
"tags":["business", "magazine", "sales", "news"]}
```

i dont even know what is wrong with my code.
i always got this error : [image]

pls help me to fix this out.
many thanks in advance.

Comment: Remove the new lines in your documents and you'll be fine. Each document must be on a single line

Comment: @Val what line bro?

Answer (score 2):

Each document must be on a single line (i.e. MUST NOT contain any newlines). Send your bulk query like this:

```
POST /ecommerce/product/_bulk
{"index":{"_id":"1002"}}
{"name":"SWA magazine", "price":"90.000", "description":"swa magazine description","status":"active", "quantity":3, "categories":[{"name":"magazine"}], "tags":["business", "magazine", "sales", "news"]}
{"index":{"_id":"1003"}}
{"name":"SWA magazine", "price":"90.000", "description":"swa magazine description", "status":"active", "quantity":3, "categories":[{"name":"magazine"}], "tags":["business", "magazine", "sales", "news"]}
```

When pasted in Sense, you should only have lines 1 through 5, not 1 through 9.