# Elasticsearch - Sense - Indexing JSON files?

Tags: json, elasticsearch, kibana, sense

I'm trying to load some JSON files to my local ES instance via Sense, but I can't seem to figure the code out. I know ES has the Bulk API and the Index API, but I can't seem to bring the code together. How can I upload/index JSON files to my local ES instance using Sense? Thank you!

Comment: This answer showing how to send a bulk query via Sense might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38069413/insertion-bulk-data-not-work-elastic-search/38069512#38069512

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, ES has a bulk api to upload JSON files to the ES cluster. I don't think that API is exposed in low level languages as in case of Sense it is Javascript in the browser. High level clients are available in Java or C# which expose more control over the ES cluster. I don't think chrome browser will support execution of this command.

To upload a JSON file to elastic using the bulk api.

1) This command uploads JSON documents from a JSON file.

```
curl -s -XPOST localhost:9200/_bulk --data-binary @path_to_file;
```

2)The JSON file should be formatted as follows:

```
{ "index" : { "_index" : "test", "_type" : "type1", "_id" : "1" } }
{ "field1" : "value1" }
{ "index" : { "_index" : "test", "_type" : "type1", "_id" : "1" } }
{ "field1" : "value3" }
{ "index" : { "_index" : "test", "_type" : "type1", "_id" : "1" } }
{ "doc" : {"field2" : "value2"} }
```

Where JSON object `doc` represents each JSON object data and the corresponding index JSON object represent metadata for that particular JSON doc like document id, type in index,index name.

[link to bulk upload](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-bulk.html)

Also you can refer my previous [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38615285/how-to-load-an-external-json-template-file-into-elasticsearch/38619056#38619056)